# How to find average from multiple lines of a text file

Tags: c#

I need to take a number from every line of a text file and find the average. I'm using stream reader to take the number out of a text file, I don't know where to go from here. Here's what I've done so far

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("pupilSkiTimes.txt"))
{
    string line = "";
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] components = line.Split("~".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        skiTime.Add(components[7]);
    }
    sr.Close();
}
```

How do I get this to read from every line of the text file, and once that's done, how do I get the average.

In case you need to know, the data I'm trying to read is doubles, e.g "23.43"

Comment: Could you provide an *example* of the file (with the desired result), please?

Comment: Ideally, anyone answering the question should be able to copy your code, paste it into a text editor, compile it, run it, and observe the problem. And unfortunately, It is not possible with your post.

Comment: Hello @ShadySpiritomb, can you show us the line structure of your text file?

Comment: The text file has lines with different data, each seperated by "~". I only need one part of each line, which what the components[7] is for.

Comment: So `0~0~0~0~0~0~0~22.65~0~0~0` is a valid line for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I will do it, as  you mentioned in comments `components[7]` are double data that you read from the file.

We need to parse it to double, sum it up and divide it by the counting time we are able to parse the number in the file. If the number is not parsed and you want the total average of all lines then move the count out of the if statement.

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("pupilSkiTimes.txt"))
{
    string line;
    double sum = 0;
    int count = 0;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] components = line.Split("~".ToCharArray(),
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        if (double.TryParse(components[7], out var result))
        {
            count++;
            sum += result;
        }
    }
    sr.Close();

    var average = sum / count;

    Console.WriteLine(average);
}
```

Comment: Just sum up and then divide by number, no need for list (hes not calculating any other metric)

Comment: Fully agreed, I am just waiting for OP response and will update my answer.

Comment: what do you need me to respond with, sorry i'm terrible at c# and don't really understand what a list will do

Comment: No problems take it easy, all of us started some where, if you have more questions just ask, and we try our best.

Comment: It's telling me that nullable reference types is not available in c# 7.3, is there a version of this that works on version 7.3?

Comment: You can remove the question mark  string? line or update your c sharp language to 8.0. I have updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, just wondering, how would I turn the double back into a string after this?

Comment: For some reason it's showing as System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Double] what does this mean, how do I fix it

Comment: Just so I do not give you arbitrary answer. What exactly have you done sine it works before. Or trying to do more.

Comment: i just tried to change the txt of a label to skiTime

Comment: averageSkiTimeLBL.Text = skiTime.ToString();

Comment: I am out now will look at it when I back

Comment: I fixed the problem, I was trying to make the label = skiTime when i should have been using average.

Comment: Cool happy to know that

Answer (score 0):

I think the handy method for this situation like this is useful hopefully you use it, I am using a similar this in my codes.

I am passing **FilePath, Separator, and index value**

```
    static double getAvgAtIndex(string fPath, char seperator, int index)
    {
        double sum = 0;
        int counter = 0;

        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fPath))
        {

            string line = "";
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                double rawData = 0;
                string[] lineData = line.Split(seperator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                double.TryParse(lineData[index], out rawData);

                sum += rawData;
                counter++;
            }
            sr.Close();
        }

        return sum / counter;
    }
```

Usage of this,

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The Avg is: {0}", getAvgAtIndex(@"..\myTextFile.txt", '~' ,1)); 
        // The Avg is: 34.688
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to use LINQ to clean up the code a bit

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = File.ReadAllLines("pupilSkiTimes.txt")
                     .Select((line)=> line.Split("~".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));

        List<double> skiTime = new List<double>();
        foreach (var parts in data)
        {
            if (double.TryParse(parts[7], out double x))
            {
                skiTime.Add(x);
            }

        }

        double average = skiTime.Average();
    }

}
```